# Replaced the anode rod on my water heater!

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, anode

We bought the house in 2019 and thought it would be a good time to replace the anode rod. Given that it was my first time doing this, I was somewhat surprised to find the rod had completely corroded.

We haven't had any problems prior to or since it was replaced, and I have the water heater scheduled to be upgraded (I think it is about 30 years old). But wondered if anyone had any experience with old water heaters being pushed to the limits in terms of their lifespan [image: old anode rod]

Comment: They fail when they fail, and it's usually messy. If they are not in an area that will cause great trouble when they fail, you can push them to the limit, but it makes shopping for a new one rushed, as opposed to being able to select with care and wait for a deal. Also see if your utility has any rebate deals going that might help your final cost.

Comment: They’ll also rust internally, spreading rust granules into tubing downstream. If you have copper pipes, this can cause rust through perforations even before the water heater fails catastrophically.

Comment: How large is the water heater? Electric or gas?  Large resistive electrics are now unobtanium - they banned them.

Comment: Is your unit gas or electric, and what size is its tank?

Comment: Electric water heater (50 gallons)